# New pages in CodeIgniter on a big website

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I have a website with many scripts written in "pure" PHP, i.e. no specific framework has been used to write the files. Furthermore, all the URLs are custom using `.htaccess` and specific PHP scripts.

For a smooth transition, I would like to start using CodeIgniter for new pages without disrupting access to the old pages, but all the documentation I've seen on CodeIgniter gives the impression that the whole website (perhaps with a few exceptions) needs to be based on the framework.

Would it be possible to use the framework for single pages here and there while leaving old URLs and code intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

You could access the CI framework from a subfolder, for instance, leaving the existing site untouched.

i.e

```
www.site.com/my_new_app/controller/method/
```

where `my_new_app` is the renamed `application` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go on the assumption that you already have a basic template system in place, and are able to render full pages with your existing site. Since Codeigniter is really just a framework, there's nothing to stop you from using vanilla php, like `include`, or additional libraries and classes. So, one thing you can do is dump your site into a sub directory in your `views` folder, then create a "master" controller which does nothing but load full html pages.

```
class Master extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        // We're expecting something like "registration/how-to-apply" here
        // Whatever your URL is. The .php extension is optional
        $args = func_get_args();
        $path = 'path_to_my_old_site/'.explode('/', $args);
        $this->load->view($path);
    }

}

// Then use this in config/routes.php
$route['(:any)'] = 'master/index/$1';
```

This will route **all** pages through the master controller. So, `yoursite.com/pages/faq` will load the file `application/views/old_site/pages/faq.php`. You can apply different routes as you see fit.

This way, you can take your time migrating to use Codeigniter conventions, one page at a time.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this would be impractical since I already have a complex URL-rewrite system set up using both mod_rewrite and custom PHP-scripts.

Comment: Yes, you would have to move the rewrites to `routes.php` with this method, and perhaps there are too many to manage.